# Vuex Mutation not Updating State

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm having a little of issue here. My mutation doesn't update the state until I refresh the page.

**Action**

```
async restoreDeletedCours({ commit }, cours) {
  let response = await Axios.post("/dashboard/school/cours/restoreDeletedCours", cours);
  let crs = response.data.data;
  if (response.status == 200 || response.status == 201) { 
    commit("REMOVE_COURS_FROM_DELETED_LIST", crs);
    commit("RESTORE_SCHOOL_DELETED_COURS", crs);
    return response.data;
  }
}
```

**MUTATION**

```
REMOVE_COURS_FROM_DELETED_LIST(state, crs) {
   // Let's remove the restored Item from deleted List
   let removeFromDeletedList = state.deletedCourses.filter(c => c.id != crs.id);
   state.deletedCourses = removeFromDeletedList;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean that your mutation does not update until refresh of page?  Do you mean that the state for deletedCourses is mutating and you are just not seeing the render?  If so you may need to use this.$nextTick to update the DOM.  Seeing the component code using deletedCourses may help me provide a better answer.

Comment: What I meant is the action successfully commit the payload to the mutation but the mutation doesn’t update the deletedCourses State. Refreshing the page will set the state with new data from the backend. What I really need here is that when I restore the the deleted records, the deletedCourses state  should update by removing the restored records which is an array of objects returned from the backend as you can see above.

Comment: This is the reference to consider:  https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules  Generally speaking, I would filter inside the action and commit the new filtered array to deletedCourses state.  The idea is to replace the object (in this case an array) with a fresh one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the [reactivity of the Mutation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays), the way you are mutating the array is not reactive, arrays are reactive when treated well, whether they are local variables from a component or Vuex states they have the same behavior:

This assignation is not reactive for arrays

```js
state.deletedCourses = removeFromDeletedList;
```

Try this instead:

Mutation:

```js
REMOVE_COURS_FROM_DELETED_LIST(state, crs) {

  //We get the indexes that we have to remove

  let indexArr = state.reduce(function(acc, val, index) {
    if (val != crs.id) {
      acc.push(index);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  //We iterate this indexes and mutate properly the state array so changes are reactive

  indexArr.forEach( i => state.deletedCourses.splice(i,1) );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for thanking your time to answer this question. I tried your approach and it is making the state Reactive, but first I had to change this portion of code `state.deletedCourses.reduce`. BUT the big problem is that when I delete restore a record, instead of removing the restored record from `deletedCourses` state, it will remove the half of objects in State. For example if there is array of objects [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], it will remove [0,2,4,6]. I tried to have fixed but without success.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying.
Edit the question and add more information about the problem that you are having now so we can try to help.